# Unauthorized access on Back4App LiveQuery

Tags: parse-platform, back4app

So I have enabled LiveQuery within Back4App and was given a link, in this format: http://mapglider.b4a.io/

Does anyone know what headers/params are needed to successfully get a response? The response that I'm getting is "Unauthorized" and I can't find in the docs any details on how to make a successful request using Postman.

Comment: Live Queries require an open socket connection to work, so by definition, they won't work using REST calls. You can find additional information about it here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/3245#issuecomment-269455063

Have you tried using a Parse SDK for that?

Answer (score 0):

If you open back4app dashboard. You can see at the left side API part.

Click the API. and it will open. You can see the relevant API part of your application. In there have headers information your app.